# Python freezing: How to find which modules depend on a given module / package

Tags: python, py2exe, cx-freeze

Freezing a Python app with `cx_Freeze` or `py2exe` I often get many unnecessary (big) modules / packages included in the frozen zip archive. Things which are imported conditionally under unused conditions and which I can exclude by an option after inspecting (all) the responsible importing code.

Thus, for the task of inspection how can I find out efficiently which modules depend on a (suspicious) given module / package - starting from a main (freeze) script.

Comment: 3 years ago, and no answer yet. cx_freeze is really annoying actually